# Don't receive data and recv() returns 0

Tags: c, sockets, networking, tcp

I'm writing my first client/server program. Client sends name of a file and server should send the file (if exists).
Server:

```
while(1)
    {
        client_sock_fd = accept(listening_sock_fd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL);
        if (client_sock_fd == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: accept()\n");
            continue;
        }

        if (!fork())
        {
            close(listening_sock_fd);

            if ((numbytes = recv(client_sock_fd, buff, 1023, 0)) == -1){
                fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: recv()\n");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }

            buff[numbytes] = '\0';

            FILE *f = fopen(buff, "r");

            if (f == NULL){
                if ((send(client_sock_fd, "FAIL", 4, 0)) == -1)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: send()\n");
                }
            }else {

                if ((send(client_sock_fd, "OK", 2, 0)) == -1)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: send()\n");
                }

                char * buffer = 0;
                long length;


                fseek (f, 0, SEEK_END);
                length = ftell (f);
                fseek (f, 0, SEEK_SET);
                if((buffer = malloc (length)) == NULL){
                    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: malloc()\n");
                    exit(1);
                }
                if (buffer)
                {
                    fread (buffer, 1, length, f);
                }
                fclose (f);


                char str[1024];
                sprintf(str, "%d", (int)strlen(buffer));
                if ((send(client_sock_fd, str, strlen(str), 0)) == -1)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: send()\n");
                }

                int s = sendall(client_sock_fd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
                if (s == -1){
                    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: send()\n");
                    free(buffer);
                    exit(1);
                }


                free(buffer);
            }

            close(client_sock_fd);
            exit(0);
        }
        close(client_sock_fd);
    }

int sendall(int s, char *buf, int len)
{
    int total = 0;
    int bytesleft = len;
    int n;

    while(total < len) {
        n = send(s, buf+total, bytesleft, 0);
        if (n == -1) { break; }
        total += n;
        bytesleft -= n;
    }

    return n==-1?-1:0;
}
```

Client:

```
if ((sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: chyba pri socket()\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(args.port_num);

    if ((prlHst = gethostbyname(argv[args.host_name])) == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: gethostbyname()\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    memcpy(&serv_addr.sin_addr, prlHst->h_addr_list[0], prlHst->h_length);

    if (connect(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: connect()\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

if ((send(sock_fd, argv[args.file], strlen(argv[args.file]), 0)) == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: send()\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if ((numbytes = recv(sock_fd, buff, 1023, 0)) == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: recv()\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    buff[numbytes] = '\0';

    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[args.file], "w");
    if (fp == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: fopen()\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (!strcmp(buff, "OK")){
        if ((numbytes = recv(sock_fd, buff, 1023, 0)) == -1){
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: recv()\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        char *pEnd;
        long int dataToRead = strtol(buff, &pEnd, 10);
        long int readData = 0;

        fprintf(stderr, "data to read %lu\n", dataToRead);

        while (readData < dataToRead) {
            unsigned char buffer [4096] = {0};
            int nbuffer;
            for (nbuffer = 0; nbuffer < 4096; ) {

                int len = recv(sock_fd, buffer, 4096, 0);
                if (len == -1){
                    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: recv()\n");
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }
                /* FIXME: Error checking */

                nbuffer += len;
                readData += len;

            }

            fwrite(buffer, sizeof(unsigned char), nbuffer, fp);
        }
```

Everything works fine until the while loop in client. `recv` always returns `0`. Why is that? What's wrong in my code? I tried to write something to the wanted file send with one `send` and it was received. Also I checked `dataToRead` variable and it's ok, containing the expected value. Thanks for replies!

Comment: Return value of 0 usually indicates the socket has been closed. In the client, where are you initializing the socket? Couldn't see it in your code sample.

Comment: OK, you find the file, get its length, allocate a 'length' size buffer for the whole file, (not a good idea in general), and then... inexcplicably, fall back to using strlen(buffer) for the folowing code:((    You already know the length, so why waste time on strlen() calls and make you code incapable of handling data with null bytes in it?

Comment: @JonathonOgden I added the initialization, @jxh I tried it with a file containing 5 characters, so in `dataToRead` I had value `6`.

Comment: When reading the file length in the client, you forgot the 'buff[numbytes] = '\0'; after the recv() call, so compromising the strtol() call by passing it a buffer that is not guaranteed terminated.

Comment: @MartinJames I tried to use length instead of strlen(). The same behaviour.

Comment: OK, so you are probably only transferring text.    You fixed the 5/6 discrepancy?

Comment: @MartinJames Yes, I was just transferring text `hello!`. What do you mean by 5/6 discrepancy?

Comment: 'I tried it with a file containing 5 characters, so in dataToRead I had value 6' - actually, you file had 6 chars in it, so no problem.

Comment: How does it ever get out of this loop: 'for (nbuffer = 0; nbuffer < 4096; )' if the file has less than 4096 bytes?

Comment: What is the point of that for loop ayway?  You already have the while.

Comment: Your code has many little errors, and so any of these things can cause your program to not work the way you expect. However, it is possible that the client program read in the file length and the file itself all in one go. That would mean the next `recv` would be `0` because the server finished sending the file.

Comment: @jxh yeah.. the lack of a secure/reliable protocol for the name/size metadata was on my list:)

Comment: I found the problem. Client received more than one send from the server at once and so it was doing unexpected things. Now I check received messages more properly and it works fine. (I also used just one loop as you said)

Answer (score 0):

> Everything works fine until the while loop in client. recv always returns 0.
>    Why is that?

It means the peer has closed the connection.

> What's wrong in my code?

You're not recognizing the condition, closing the socket, and ceasing attempting to read from it. This is what you must do when `recv()` returns 0, or indeed when it returns -1 with `errno` equal to anything except `EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK`.

> I tried to write something to the wanted file send with one send and it was received. Also I checked dataToRead variable and it's ok, containing the expected value.

I fail to see what this has to do with it.

Your copy loops are ludicrously over-complex. The canonical way to transfer bytes from a socket to a file until end of stream on the socket is as follows:

```
while ((count = recv(socket, buffer, sizeof buffer)) > 0)
{
    write(file, buffer, count);
}
```

and conversely for transferring bytes from a file to a socket:

```
while ((count = read(file, buffer, sizeof buffer)) > 0)
{
    send(socket, buffer, count);
}
```